# BeautifulSoup and div value from site using Firefox

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

After some changes I got thi:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com"))

soup.find("div", {"id": "botloc"})

elem = soup.find('div')
print elem['id'], 'is the id'
print elem.text, 'is the value'
```

So finaly i wrote correct code (with forum help) but the value in respond is wrong becouse its taking it from google chrome! 
Any ideas how to get div value from firefox? (i am loged on server on the firefox browser) 
I apreciate every tip

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the HTML source is there? Maybe it's a naive question, but it's very common that people aren't checking all the steps that their code goes through. Maybe you get a wrong response or *late-rendering* from JavaScript etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing it, but you're not using it...

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com"))
```